# Getting error message mentioning miniconda while inside a virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, uwsgi

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial on serving flask apps with [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/). When I'm trying to install `uwsgi` with the following command:

`pip install uwsgi`

I get the following error:

[image]

I don't understand why the error message mentions miniconda: I've created a virtual environment with

```
python3 -m venv myproject_venv
```

and activated it with

```
source myproject_venv/bin/activate
```

So I don't understand why

```
pip install uwsgi
```

would have anything to do with miniconda, since the virtual environment should be sealed off from the rest of my system. I'm sure that the `pip` command is not the same `pip` package that was installed by miniconda, since if I run

```
pip --version
```

I get

```
pip 10.0.1 from /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

and if I run

```
source myproject_venv/bin/activate
pip --version
```

I get

```
pip 18.1 from /home/ubuntu/myproject/myproject_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I thought virtual environments are supposed to be sealed off from the rest of your system. Since I didn't use miniconda to create this virtual environment, I don't understand why it's interfering with it.

**Question:** How is it possible that I get an error mentioning miniconda while I'm trying to install `uwsgi` inside a virtual environment that was not set up with miniconda? I've read some more about virtual environments and I don't get how miniconda has anything to do with my created virtual environment.

Comment: Would you please replace your screenshot with text? Can you mention also which version & distribution of Linux do you use?

Comment: Follow this tutorial if you want to setup uwsgi + nginx 
https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2016/02/10/deploying-python-web-apps-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-emperor/

Comment: @Peshmerge Would that be more convenient to you? I think an image is a bit more readable.. I'm mainly interested in the question about the virtual environment !

Comment: Text is more readable and that became a convention here on SO for posting code or output. Anyway, Honestly the problem you have is weird and indeed as you wrote, virtual env are sealed and isolated from other parts of your system, I wouldn't know why it happens!